# Iterate over nested list in c:forEach

Tags: jsp, foreach, jstl, nested-loops

Is there any other way to display data in jsp a part this method

```
<c:forEach var = "listValue" items = "${tableView.tableHeaders}">
<tr>
  <%for(int i = 0;i<5;i++){ %>
            <td>
                <%=${listValue.get(i)} %>
            </td>
        <%} %>
</tr>
```

Comment: So you want to iterate list value without java right? If so let me know the type of list is?

Answer (score 1):

You should at least change the number of iterations:

```
<c:forEach var = "listValue" items = "${tableView.tableHeaders}">
<tr>
    <%for(int i = 0;i<listValue.size();i++){ %>
        <td>
            <%=${listValue.get(i)} %>
        </td>
    <%} %>
</tr>
```

Comment: This will not work as you can't access jstl parameter directly in java code

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using JSTL only:

```
<c:forEach var = "listValue" items = "${tableView.tableHeaders}">
<tr>
  <c:forEach var = "listVal" items = "${listValue}">
            <td>
                ${listVal}
            </td>
  </c:forEach>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Hope this will help you.